# Xamarin.Forms keeping text in the middle of a scrollview enlarged?

Tags: c#, xamarin, scrollview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I have a pretty vague description of something I'd like to do, but not entirely sure if it's possible. Well, more accurately not entirely sure of the best way to go about it.

Say I have a single ScrollView and my device is in landscape mode. I have 15 Label objects each on their own line so most of them are off the screen. The user can scroll up and down as you would expect. That's all fine.

For talking sake let's assume that we can only fit 5 Label objects on the screen at any one time. How would I go about ensuring that the middle item of text (the third) on screen at all times has a larger font size? I.e. if the user continues to scroll down the fourth item would become the new centre item and thus be enlarged. Even better, the first and fifth items would be even smaller.

Does that make any sense?

It's kind of like on an iPhone when you're selecting a Month, it's a spinner effect where the middle item (the one that is selected) is always highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you're going to get out of the box. You can either create a custom control and relative custom renderer and build it all out manually, or you could tap into the ScrollView.Scrolled event, then look at the ScrollView.ScrollY value, and then iterate your Labels manually adjusting the FontSize property based on some calculations of how close they are to the scroll position.